# http post angularjs localhost json array

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send a post to my localhost from an ionic application but fails. I need to send a json object in the following format

```
{
   "usuario" : {
       "usuario" : "test",
       "password" : "123456"
   }
}
```

I'm sending it like this:

```
.factory('User', ['$http', function($http, UrlLogin) {

    return {
        login: function(username, password) {
           var data = {usuario : {username : username, password : password}};
           return $http({
               method:'post', 
               url: 'http://localhost:60225/Login', 
               data: data,
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
           })
        }
    }
}])
```

So I call my factory from the controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, User) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.login = function(){
    //var userJsonArray = {"usuario ": { "username " : $scope.data.username, "password" : $scope.data.password}};
    User.login($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password)
      .then(function(response){
          alert(JSON.stringify({data: response.data}));
      }, function(response){
          alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: response.data}));
      });
  }
});
```

However I do not get a good response, it falls into error and I can not verify that. POSTMAN use to test my service and everything works fine, it's the same format you need to send.

Now I posted my asp service, I get the following error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource CORS

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Show us the error - Does it reach the server ?

Comment: @SayusiAndo At least the side of my service none, nor is a syntax error, only I get null message failure.

Comment: My service is in .net, Interrupted I put a point to see if it came to the service but not reach the server.

Comment: If you use IIS express pay attention to the right ports, as far as I know it might change frequently.

Comment: Double check the URL and port and everything seems ordinary. @SayusiAndo

Comment: Do I understand correctly, there is not data at server side, I mean .NET Controller side?

Comment: I think the post is not done, because I do not receive any request.

Comment: i thnk you should publish your api on localhost IIS server which would be running on port 80 or 8080 and may be you can get the response then,

Comment: Can you post screeenshot of your server running? Also the API code for the `login` API in .Net.

Comment: I'm publish, I comment as I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic as [a post on his blog](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) about that, you may read it ;)